# Limit with $ \cos (\frac{\pi }{x} )$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow2}  \left(\frac { \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{x} \right)}{x-2}\right)$$
You are supposed to take $t = \frac {\pi}{2} + \frac {\pi}{x}$

A step-by-step solution would be helpful

Comment: Asking for a step-by-step solution instead of showing your own attempt is the best way to get your question downvoted.

Comment: One way is to notice that $\cos(\pi/2) = 0$ so the limit can be written $\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{f(x) - f(2)}{x-2}$ with $f(x) = \cos(\pi/x)$. This is the definition of $f'(2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Recognize: $$\left(\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{x})}{x-2}\right) = \left(\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{x})- \cos(\frac{\pi}{2})}{x-2}\right) = \frac{\pi}{\xi^2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{\xi}\right)$$

where the last equations follows from the mean value theorem.

for a $\xi \in (x,2)$.

For $x\to 2$ also $\xi \to 2$

Comment: Very nice...but perhaps writing the word "derivative" is in place if you already solved the central limit. +1

Comment: Thx… I had the sentence about mean value theorem but then it vanished ^^

Comment: Thx, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\cos{x}=\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x\right)$, so $\cos{\dfrac{\pi}{x}}$ can be written as $\sin\left({\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\dfrac{\pi}{x}}\right)=\sin{\left(\dfrac{\pi(x-2)}{2x}\right)}$

So, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow2}  \left(\frac { \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{x} \right)}{x-2}\right)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow2}\left(\dfrac{\sin{\left(\dfrac{\pi(x-2)}{2x}\right)}}{x-2}\right)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow2}\left(\dfrac{\sin{\left(\dfrac{\pi(x-2)}{2x}\right)}}{\left(\dfrac{\pi(x-2)}{2x}\right)(x-2)}\cdot\left(\dfrac{\pi(x-2)}{2x}\right)\right)\\
=\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow2}\left(\dfrac{\sin{\left(\dfrac{\pi(x-2)}{2x}\right)}}{\left(\dfrac{\pi(x-2)}{2x}\right)}\cdot\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2x}\right)\right)$

Now using the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\dfrac{\sin{f(x)}}{f(x)}=1$, where as $x\rightarrow a$ $f(x)\rightarrow 0$. So, using this property we get the required limit as

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow2}  \left(\frac { \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{x} \right)}{x-2}\right)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow2}\left(\dfrac{\sin{\left(\dfrac{\pi(x-2)}{2x}\right)}}{\left(\dfrac{\pi(x-2)}{2x}\right)}\cdot\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2x}\right)\right)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow2}\left(\dfrac{\sin{\left(\dfrac{\pi(x-2)}{2x}\right)}}{\left(\dfrac{\pi(x-2)}{2x}\right)}\right)\cdot\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow2}\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2x}\right)\\
=1\cdot\dfrac{\pi}{4}$

Hence, we get $\boxed{\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow2}  \left(\frac { \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{x} \right)}{x-2}\right)=\dfrac{\pi}{4}}$